# Foreach last item with condition

Tags: php

```
foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
    if ($item->isNotCancelled()) {
        echo 'ITEM....<br />';
        // if last NOT CANCELLED item:
        echo '<strong>ITEM....</strong><br />';
    } else {
        // ignored completely
    }
}
```

I need to add `<strong>` arround the last item which did not get cancelled... I know how to check the last item of an array or iterator, but with the condition in the `if` case, how'd you do this?

Will I need 2 loops?

---

**Update & Solution**: I solved this by reversing the logic and to find the first item rather than the last.

I'll keep the question up if someone wants to comment or answer anyways.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$i=0;
$counter=0;
foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
    if ($item->isNotCancelled()) {
       $counter=$i;
   }
  $i++;
}
 $i=0;
  foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
    if ($item->isNotCancelled()) {
      if( $counter==$i){
      echo "<strong>".$item."</strong></br>"
     }
   }
  $i++;
}
```

what about this?

Comment: Nice idea, I would have to prevent the last item getting double printed and anyways, what if the last item after foreach is cancelled?

Answer (score 1):

```
$lastNonCancelledItem = null;
foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
    if ($item->isNotCancelled()) {
        echo 'ITEM....<br />';
        $lastNonCancelledItem = $item;
    } else {
        // ignored completely
    }
}

echo '<strong>' $lastNonCancelledItem; //profit
```

If display these items is a complex task that you do not wish to repeat in 2 places make some sort of function to display the item

```
$lastNonCancelledItem = null;
foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
    if ($item->isNotCancelled()) {
        $view->showItem($item);
        $lastNonCancelledItem = $item;
    } else {
        // ignored completely
    }
}

echo $view->showItem($lastNonCancelledItem, TYPE_STRONG); //profit (or whatever)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
    $coun = count($orderItems);
    $i=1;
    foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
        if ($item->isNotCancelled()) {
            echo 'ITEM....<br />';
            // if last NOT CANCELLED item:

        }else {
          // ignored completely
       }
         if($i==($coun-1))
            echo '<strong>ITEM....</strong><br />';
        $i++;
    }
```

Comment: What if the last item (`$i==($coun-1)`) is cancelled? => nothing get's strong'ed :)